# Need help identifying a couple of Lego sets, grey tank with 4 short legs, and ship with long wings with lime green tiles

Tags: building, set-identification

Do you recognize either of the below Lego sets?

We received them as a hand-me-down gift with no instructions.

Thanks for any help!

[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Top set is indeed 75013 as per @lego-related username's answer.

Bottom set is [75024 HH-87 Starhopper](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75024-1#T=P).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Top set is number 75013, [Umbaran MHC (Mobile Heavy Cannon)](http://brickset.com/sets/75013-1/Umbaran-MHC-(Mobile-Heavy-Cannon)). I think the previous owner modified the cannon, because the actual set looks vastly different up there. I don't recognize the bottom set, but it looks like some star wars set.

Answer (score 2):

The second set is [75024-1: HH-87 Starhopper](http://brickset.com/sets/75024-1/HH-87-Starhopper)